# Create a function that calculates the sum of a series

Tags: python, python-3.x

# write a function called series_sum() that prompts the user for a non-negative
   # interger n. If the user enters a negative the function should return None
   # otherwise the function should return the sum of the following series, 
   # 1000 + (1/1)**2 + (1/2)**2 + (1/3)**2 + (1/4)**2 ... + (1/n)**2

```
def series_sum():
    n = input("Please enter a number greater than 0")
```

Answer (score 0):

Full functionality:

```
def series_sum(n):
    if n >= 0:
        return 1000 + sum((1/x) ** 2 for x in range(1, n + 1))
```

Or with same functionality, but making negatives explicit:

```
def series_sum(n):
  if n >=0:
     return 1000 + sum((1/x) ** 2 for x in range(1, n + 1))  
  if n < 0:
     return None
```

Comment: In case you're new to SO, don't forget to up-vote answers, comments etc that helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

The function needs to take one argument, n.

Next.... for the sum... range(1,n+1) will create an iterable object from 1 to n that you can use in a for loop. Under your else statement, create a variable 'total'.. it starts out as 1000. For each value in the range 1 to n, you'll add 1 over the value squared to total.

```
def series_sum():
     n = input("Please enter an integer greater than 0")
     n = int(n)
     if n < 0:
          return None
     else:
          numbers = range(1,n+1)
          total = 1000 
          for number in numbers:
               total = total + 1/n**2
          return total
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def series_sum():
    n = input("Please enter a number greater than 0")
    if type(n,str):
        try:
            n = int(n)
        except:
            print 'enter integer value'
            return
    if n >=0:
        sum = 1000
        for i in range(1,n+1):
            sum += (1./i)**2
        return sum
    return
```

Comment: It happened by click mistake.I was still working on it.